# Pass Parameter in MVC using a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an app for creating Exams.  After creating a new question I would like to pass the question_id parameter to the questions_choices create action.  I have created a list of questions choices to do 4 at a time (A, B, C, & D) in the action.  I am having difficultly in passing the question_id into the list.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult CreateNewChoice(int? id)
    {
        var questions_choices = new List<questions_choices>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            questions_choices.Add(new questions_choices());               
        }                 
        return View(questions_choices);
    }
```

I would like to implement something like this within the list but a little confused how.

```
questions_choices questions_choices = new questions_choices();
        questions_choices.questions_id = id;
```

Model

```
 public partial class questions_choices
{
    public long questions_choices_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> questions_id { get; set; }
    public string questions_choices_value { get; set; }
    public string questions_choices_string { get; set; }  
}
```

If a put the two together I have issues with the variable being declared twice.

Comment: What part are you actually having difficulty with?

Comment: can you provide questions_choices model?

Comment: Added Model to description

Comment: you mean you want to assign 1,2,3,4 to questions_id seperately?

Comment: same questions_id for all 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
 public ActionResult CreateNewChoice(int? id)
    {
        var questions_choices = new List<questions_choices>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            questions_choices.Add(new questions_choices(){questions_id = id});               
        }                 
        return View(questions_choices);
    }
```

it will assign `id` of the parameter to the `questions_id` to all 4 questions

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't know you could pass parameters that way

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult CreateNewChoice(int? id)
    {
    var questions_choices = new List<questions_choices>();
    questions_choices Objquestion;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Objquestion = new questions_choices();
        Objquestion.questions_id = id;
        questions_choices.Add(Objquestion);               
    }                 
    return View(questions_choices);
    }
```